# What is the bootloader used in STM32 bluepill boards?

Tags: arduino, bootloader, stm32f1

Are the bootloaders used by Arduino blue pill is pre-installed bootloaders by chip manufacturer or are they built by Arduino? If so can I replace the Arduino bootloader(not USB bootloader) to the STM32 fresh chip(with manufacturer bootloader) using FTDI programmer? Here I just have an STM32F103 MCU(fresh chip) board(not blue pill) with FTDI connector,boot0 and boot1 configuration jumper also have pins to get 3.3v and GND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ST-Link , after erasing the blue chip, I copied the bootloader from a "black pill" (Robotdyn) into the cheap "blue pill": it worked immediately.

[image: The blue pill showed:]

grts
rik

Answer (score 0):

> Are the bootloaders used by Arduino blue pill is pre-installed
>   bootloaders by chip manufacturer or are they built by Arduino?

Blue pill is not Arduino.

It does not have Arduino compatible bootloader.

It makes almost no sense to program those chips Arduino way. Buy STM32 Nucleo board with the built in debugger.

Comment: I have an STM32 board which can be a program through Arduino IDE using an FTDI programmer

Comment: I did not write that you cant use Arduino IDE (using SW debug probes). But it is the most inefficient way way of coding: primitive IDE, no debugging etc etc

Comment: Ha..... That's true! In my project, I don't have a choice other than Arduino. So please let me know the that can I upload an Arduino serial boot loader(boot loader for STM32 not  USB bootloader) to STM32F blue pill module using SWD programmer without changing any boot pins. please revive me here!....... Sorry for the late comment.